# Link another commit's reference in commit message gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit

I know we can mention issue in commit messages as'#issue_no', but is it possible to link it to another commit in gitlab?

either mention commit SHA or complete commit URL in the commit message?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See the documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/markdown.html#special-gitlab-references

> | references | input | cross-project reference | shortcut inside same namespace |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | specific commit | `9ba12248` | `namespace/project@9ba12248` | `project@9ba12248` |

So you can just use the commit hash within one project.

Comment: This applies if the commit is in the same project. Commits in other projects of the same Gitlab instance can also be cross-referenced with the full link or sth. like `namespace/project@9ba12248`.

Comment: In some workflows, commit hashes can change. That's why a slightly more verbose style of a reference to a commit is also used: `git log -1 --format=reference`. See [section "PRETTY FORMATS" in documentation of `git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats).